# How to send internet connection type to server in swift: Alamofire

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

How to assign an internet connection type to string variable. Please someone help me. This is my code

```
reachabilityManager?.listener = { checkConection in
            switch checkConection {
            case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
                print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")
                break
            case .notReachable:
                print("internet is not reachable")
                break
            case .reachable(.wwan):
                print("internet is not working with status \(checkConection)")
                break
            case .unknown:
                print("internet status is unknown")
                break
            }
            print("Data",checkConection)
        }
    }
    reachabilityManager?.startListening()
```

I have to send that string param to the server.

Comment: What is `reachabilityManager`? Is it coming from a library or did you declare it. If you declared it, you should include the declaration for the type of `checkConnection`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Its coming from library

Comment: Then you should state what library you're using, otherwise it's quite hard to help.

Comment: Sry @DávidPásztor let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager() that is declered from globle.

Comment: I am using Alamofire

Comment: But what is need to do like this, means send string param to the server, if internet connection is not reachable how you call API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `checkConnection` has a custom `enum` type of Alamofire, `NetworkReachabilityStatus` ([Alamofire source code](https://github.com/leancloud/Swift-Sample-Code/blob/master/Pods/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift)), which doesn't have a raw value nor does it conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.

To get a `String` value from the `enum`, you can make it conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and then use the `description` property of it. Just make sure to also do this for `ConnectionType`, which is another `enum` and it is the associated value of `NetworkReachabilityStatus.Reachable`.

```
extension ConnectionType: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .EthernetOrWiFi:
            return "Ethernet of WiFi"
        case .WWAN:
            return "WWAN"
        }
    }
}

extension NetworkReachabilityStatus: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .NotReachable:
            return "Not Reachable"
        case .Unknown:
            return "Unknown"
        case let .Reachable(connectionType):
            return "Reachable through \(connectionType.description)"
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your code:

```
var reachabilityStatusString: NetworkReachabilityStatus?

reachabilityManager?.listener = { checkConection in
    reachabilityStatusString = checkConnection.description
    print("Reachability status: \(reachabilityStatusString ?? "Unknown")")
}
reachabilityManager?.startListening()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @David, Its working